# Facing error during compilation of Iterative closest point algorithm

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library

I am trying to compile the program from this site.

(http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php)!

But during compilation i faced the following error.

> `'pcl::Registration<PointSource,PointTarget,Scalar>::setInputCloud' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'    \sample\kinect2_grabber.h   424 1   Sample`

the code which got the error is as follows:-

```
icp.setInputCloud (cloud);
icp.setInputTarget (cloud);
```

I have declared this cloud inside the function `convertRGBDepthToPointXYZRGB` like this

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud( new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>() );
```

I don't know how to rectify the above error.Please somebody help me to solve the above error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the line where you declare and initialise pcl::IterativeClosestPoint?

Comment: i have declared it inside protected modifier.                                   protected:
IterativeClosestPoint<PointXYZ, PointXYZ> icp;
;

Answer (score 0):

You have templated the `IterativeClosestPoint` object on type `pcl::PointXYZ` for both template arguments, so that the functons `setInputCloud` and `setInputTarget`, whose argument types are determined by the class template, expect an object of `pcl::PointXYZ` as their argument. However, you are trying to pass `pcl::PointXYZRGB` to the object. Instead, template the object on `pcl::PointXYZRGB` for both source and target.

API for the `IterativeClosestPoint` class:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1_iterative_closest_point.html

Comment: pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr finalcloud;
but if i do icp.align(finalcloud) then it throws following error.

Comment: no instance of overloaded function "pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<PointSource, PointTarget, Scalar>::align [with PointSource=pcl::PointXYZRGB, PointTarget=pcl::PointXYZRGB, Scalar=float]" matches the argument list argument types are: (boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>>)      object type is: pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB, float>

Comment: In this case the error message is more clear: the align() function does not take an argument of type boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> - see the API for the correct argument type: http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1_registration.html#a96212303ca16b6d60020824086887c4f